# Tiki File upload failed: Potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) detected

Tags: tiki-wiki

I really don't know where to start on this one.  I have configured Tiki to use the File Galleries feature.  Every time I try to upload a file, I get an error.  I have tried to for a couple of days to find the right Google search but have had no luck.

[image]

or

[image]
The error occurs using the admin account or a regular user account.

I am using Tiki 20.2svn.

Comment: That's odd - that CSRF one happens even on a freshly reloaded page does it?
Any patten to the two error messages?
Are there any error messages in the JavaScript Console?
Maybe try turning off jQuery Upload on the File Gallery Control Panel?
Also maybe try switching to branch 21.x (should be the same though)

Comment: I turned jQuery Uploads off and tried again.  I did not see anything in the JavaScript Console, but I get a new error:  "A temporary folder is missing".  I checked the permissions for the upload folder I have specified for files and the permissions look good.  I even logged in as a regular user and was able to touch a file.

Comment: Aha, maybe it means the tmp folder php uses for uploading files? Maybe there's a clue in your phpinfo... is there anything in the "upload_tmp_dir" setting? (mine's empty here) do any other kind of file uploads work on your server?

Comment: I found the tiki-phpinfo.php and it was pretty empty.  Only File or Image Galleries are configured.  I learned that tiki-check.php has a Special Directories section which checks the to see if the directories are writeable.  My custom file and image directories were not writeable.  I compared the permissions with other directories and everything was the same.  I moved the file directory within the web servers base and it became writeable by the tiki-check.php standards.  Even though it is reporting writeable, I was not able to upload a file.